# How to implement more than one endpoint in a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, functions-framework

My intention is to use a unique Google Cloud Function to accommodate a few endpoints.

I do have a super simple code using the Python `functions-framework` to take an Id Token and validate whether it is valid. I'd like to add one more endpoint to revoke that Id Token. I haven't found any samples around the web. Since the decorators are not so suggestive how to create more endpoints to the same Google Cloud Function (if it is possible)?

```
import functions_framework
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth

from flask import abort

# Initialize the app
cred = credentials.Certificate('../credentials-dev.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

# Register an HTTP function with the Functions Framework
@functions_framework.http
def insert_monthly(request):
  # Validate auth
  print(request.headers)
  user_uid = validate_auth(request)

  # Return an HTTP response
  return user_uid


def validate_auth(request):
    try:
        id_token = request.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[1]
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token, check_revoked=True)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
        return uid
    except Exception as e:
        abort(400, description=str(e))
```

Comment: I discourage you to do that, but I wrote 2 articles on that, in python and go: https://medium.com/google-cloud/hack-use-cloud-functions-as-a-webserver-with-golang-42edc7935247 https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-multiple-paths-in-cloud-functions-python-and-flask-fc6780e560d3

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere. I think the Cloud Run is what I need. I found your articles just after I post the question here and it cleared my doubts, this is a nice article that gained my claps!